# permalinks of subcategory and posts

Tags: permalinks

I need to list subcategories and the posts that in it, for example:

```
<h3><a href="#">subcategory</a></h3>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">post1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">post2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">post3</a></li>
   </ul>
```

How can I make it work so the permalink of the subcategory will lead to the subcategory 
and the permalink of the posts will lead to the posts?

Answer (score 0):

use the following code should get you through your problem.

just pass the id of parent category in $term_id variable

```
<?php
    $term_id =  ;    // id for the parent category
    $taxonomy_name = 'category';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );    
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) :
      $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
?> 
<h3><a href="<?php echo get_term_link; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h3>
   <ul>
   <?php  
        $args= array('cat'=>$child,
                    'posts_per_page'=>6                                                 
                    );
        $loop= new WP_query($args);                                               
        if( $loop->have_posts()):while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post(); 
   ?>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>


   <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;

   ?>

   </ul>
<?php 
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: I get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$the_query' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply , updated the code above ,please use it and let me know if you still face any problemO

Comment: Problem was i miss types $loop as $the_query in $loop= new WP_query($args);    & forgot to put ; after $args